# 2.4GHz BLE and 900MHz LoRa coexistence

Tags: bluetooth-low-energy, pcb-antenna, lora

I am working on a new design for a simple BLE to LoRa bridge. I have a chip antenna for LoRa that covers 868-915MHz and I was following the Nordic reference design for the 2.4GHz BLE antenna. What kind of spacing does there need to be between these antennas, and do I need special features like a ground fence? Right now, they share a common edge with no other components along that edge. Cost is more important than range, but range still matters.

Any gotchas or advice would be greatly appreciated as this is new to me.

Comment: hm, the design guides for such antenna modules typically specify keep-out areas